# How can I denote the set of probability distributions over a finite set?

Tags: notation, simplex

I am trying to refer to the set of probability mass functions over a finite set $A$. If the elements in the set $A$ are numbered, referring to the simplex $\Delta^{|A|-1}$ would describe exactly what I mean.

Is there a similarly compact notation that I could use without assuming that the elements in $A$ are numbered? I'm trying to avoid writing the full definition, $\left\{p:A\to[0,1]\middle\vert \sum_{a\in A} p(a)=1\right\}$ because that would slow down the flow of the paragraph considerably.

Comment: I have seen notations like $\operatorname{Prob}(A)$, $\mathcal{P}(A)$, $\mathcal{M}_1(A)$, etc and terminology like '**probability simplex on $A$**'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In economics, the notation $\Delta A$ is common.

Comment: Accepting your own correct answer suggests that you're an economist.  I hope you won't use this where mathematicians will see it. If you must, be sure to define it for us.

Answer (score 1):

I think compact notation slows down flow more than do more words. Why not just say "the set of probability distributions on $A$"? If necessary, precede that by saying a probability distribution is a nonnegative real valued function on $A$ that sums to $1$.

Comment: You are probably right... especially if there's no real consensus on what the notation would have to be.